# How to get the position in a certain percentile range of 2-d array with np.NAN in it

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, statistics

Here is my question.
With some background intro here:

- **a** is an 2-d numpy array in the size of (50,50)
- Some elements in **a** are *np.NAN*, others has its finite values.

#### My target

> Get the array indice of each elements in the percentile range of (70, 80) for **a**

#### My attempt

1. fliter the *np.NAN* in **a**

   ```
   a_noNaN = np.array([0,])

   for i in range(0,a.shape[0],1):
    for j in range(0,a.shape[1],1):
        if (np.isnan(a[i,j]) == False):
           a_noNaN       = np.append(a_noNaN,a[i,j])

   a_noNaN = a_noNaN[1:] ## the first element "0" is redundant
   ```
2. **Sort the data in order** and determine **the value range**

   ```
   a_noNaN_sort = np.sort(a_noNaN)
   a_70 = np.percentile(a_noNaN, 70)
   a_80 = np.percentile(a_noNaN, 80)
   ```
3. Get the array indices in such value range

   ```
   k = 0
   indice    = np.array([(i, j) for i in xrange(a.shape[0]) for j in xrange(a.shape[1])])
   indice_in = np.zeros_like(indice)
   for t in range(0,indice.shape[0],1):
       for i in range(a.shape[0]):
           for j in range(a.shape[1]):
               if ((a[i,j]<a_80)& ((a[i,j]>a_70))):
                   indice_in[t] = indice[t]
   ```

I don't know my method whether right or wrong.
Is there any easier function I can use to get thing done?
Any advice would be appreciate!ヽ(✿ﾟ▽ﾟ)ノ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the numpy function [`nanpercentile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.nanpercentile.html) to avoid taking `nan` values into consideration

```
a_70 = np.nanpercentile(a, 70)
a_80 = np.nanpercentile(a, 80)
```

to find all the elements that are between the two percentiles you can use numpy's boolean indexing

```
bool_indexes = np.logical_and(a > a_70, a < a_80)
indexes = np.nonzero(bool_indexes)
```

`indexes` is going to be a 2d array with the indexes for all the elements that are between the values `a_70` and `a_80`

Simple demonstration of the execution

```
# create a random (20x20) matrix
a = np.random.randn(20,20)
a_70 = np.nanpercentile(a, 70)
a_80 = np.nanpercentile(a, 80)
bool_indexes = np.logical_and(a > a_70, a < a_80)
indexes = np.nonzero(bool_indexes)
print indexes

(array([ 0,  0,  0,  1,  2,  3,  3,  3,  5,  6,  6,  7,  7,  7,  7,  8,  8,
        8,  8,  9, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 14, 14, 14, 16, 16, 16,
       16, 17, 19, 19, 19, 19]), 
 array([ 3, 10, 16, 11,  8,  7, 10, 11,  8,  0, 11, 10, 11, 17, 19, 10, 11,
       15, 19, 17,  0,  0,  1,  8, 10,  2,  8, 19, 10, 12, 17,  0,  1,  6,
       14,  6,  3,  4,  5,  7]))
```

Comment: OP: Note that you might find that `bool_indexes` is all you really need

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The `np.logical_and` is way bettert than my attempt!